# How To Add Stroke In This Python meme maker?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to add stroke to this meme maker in python.
This code generates a meme but it does not add stroke to it.
How to do it?
When I use it, only white text appears in the resulting image. I want black border to text too.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap

def generate_meme(image_path, top_text, bottom_text='', font_path='./fonts/impact/impact.ttf', font_size=9):
    # load image
    im = Image.open(image_path)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    image_width, image_height = im.size
    
    # load font
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font=font_path, size=int(image_height*font_size)//100)

    # convert text to uppercase
    top_text = top_text.upper()
    bottom_text = bottom_text.upper()

    # text wrapping
    char_width, char_height = font.getsize('A')
    chars_per_line = image_width // char_width
    top_lines = textwrap.wrap(top_text, width=chars_per_line)
    bottom_lines = textwrap.wrap(bottom_text, width=chars_per_line)

    # draw top lines
    y = 10
    for line in top_lines:
        line_width, line_height = font.getsize(line)
        x = (image_width - line_width)/2
        draw.text((x,y), line, fill='white', font=font)
        y += line_height

    # draw bottom lines
    y = image_height - char_height * len(bottom_lines) - 15
    for line in bottom_lines:
        line_width, line_height = font.getsize(line)
        x = (image_width - line_width)/2
        draw.text((x,y), line, fill='white', font=font)
        y += line_height

    # save meme
    im.save('meme-' + im.filename.split('/')[-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its Very Simple!
Add Black Border Before Adding White Texts
Here is Code

```
def generate_meme(image_path, top_text, bottom_text='', font_path='fonts/impact.ttf', font_size=9):
    im = Image.open(image_path)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    image_width, image_height = im.size
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font=font_path, size=int(image_height * font_size) // 100)
    top_text = top_text.upper()
    bottom_text = bottom_text.upper()
    char_width, char_height = font.getsize('A')
    chars_per_line = image_width // char_width
    top_lines = textwrap.wrap(top_text, width=chars_per_line)
    bottom_lines = textwrap.wrap(bottom_text, width=chars_per_line)
    y = 10
    for line in top_lines:
        line_width, line_height = font.getsize(line)
        x = (image_width - line_width) / 2
        draw.text((x-1, y), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x+1, y), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x, y-1), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x, y+1), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x, y), line, fill='white', font=font)
        y += line_height

    y = image_height - char_height * len(bottom_lines) - 15
    for line in bottom_lines:
        line_width, line_height = font.getsize(line)
        x = (image_width - line_width) / 2
        draw.text((x-1, y), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x+1, y), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x, y-1), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x, y+1), line, font=font, fill='black')
        draw.text((x, y), line, fill='white', font=font)
        y += line_height
    file_name = "memeimg.png"
    ok = sedpath + "/" + file_name
    im.save(ok, "PNG")
```